# Unity 2018 error in using inspector to assign ButtonClickedEvent for dynamic list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have written some dynamic list to fill in unity inspector,

```
[Serializable]
public class MenuItem
{
    public string title = "Item";
    public bool enabled = true;
    public Button.ButtonClickedEvent onClick = null;
    public MenuItem[] submenu;
}
public MenuItem[] menu = null;
```

Now, when I use inspector to assign value to menu, everything is OK in first level. But after the second level I can not assign ButtonClickedEvent to created MenuItem child. I get this error in unity editor:

```
type is not a enum value
UnityEditor.SerializedProperty:set_enumValueIndex(Int32)
UnityEditorInternal.UnityEventDrawer:AddEventListener(ReorderableList) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/UnityEventDrawer.cs:355)
UnityEditorInternal.Defaults:DrawFooter(Rect, ReorderableList) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/ReorderableList.cs:115)
UnityEditorInternal.ReorderableList:DoListFooter(Rect) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/ReorderableList.cs:641)
UnityEditorInternal.ReorderableList:DoList(Rect) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/ReorderableList.cs:413)
UnityEditorInternal.UnityEventDrawer:OnGUI(Rect) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/UnityEventDrawer.cs:148)
UnityEditorInternal.UnityEventDrawer:OnGUI(Rect, SerializedProperty, GUIContent) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/UnityEventDrawer.cs:117)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

And in the inspector I see a strange 0.
[image: unity inspector error for dynamic list with ButtonClickedEvent in childs]

Answer (score 0):

Here
[UnityEvent Editor breaking in nested struct](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1339535/unityevent-editor-breaking-in-nested-struct.html)
there is an answer that recommend using ScriptableObject instead of recursive list. But there is not HOW!

But note to the point of the answer, if I have the specific number of levels, I can use something like this

```
[Serializable]
public class MenuItem
{
    public string title = "Item";
    public bool enabled = true;
    public int width = 100;
    public string relatedLeftDockPanel = "";
    public string relatedRightDockPanel = "";
    public Button.ButtonClickedEvent onClick = null;
    public MenuItemLevel1[] submenu;
}

[Serializable]
public class MenuItemLevel1
{
    public string title = "Item";
    public bool enabled = true;
    public int width = 100;
    public string relatedLeftDockPanel = "";
    public string relatedRightDockPanel = "";
    public Button.ButtonClickedEvent onClick = null;
    public MenuItemLevel2[] submenu;
}

[Serializable]
public class MenuItemLevel2
{
    public string title = "Item";
    public bool enabled = true;
    public int width = 100;
    public string relatedLeftDockPanel = "";
    public string relatedRightDockPanel = "";
    public Button.ButtonClickedEvent onClick = null;
}
```

**EDIT**: or even better

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string title = "Item";
    public bool enabled = true;
    public int width = 100;
    public string relatedLeftDockPanel = "";
    public string relatedRightDockPanel = "";
    public Button.ButtonClickedEvent onClick = null;
}

[Serializable]
public class MenuItemLevel0 : MenuItem
{
    public MenuItemLevel1[] submenu;
}

[Serializable]
public class MenuItemLevel1 : MenuItem
{
    public MenuItemLevel2[] submenu;
}

[Serializable]
public class MenuItemLevel2 : MenuItem
{
}
```

It solves the problem, but I guess there is some better solutions.